# Unable to install turicreate in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, turi-create

I am trying to install turicreate in anaconda but i unable to do it.
I tried to run a command

**conda install -c derickl turicreate**

but promt gives an error

**Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - turicreate**

I also tried by run some other commands also but none of them able to installed turicreate....
can someone help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official Conda package for Turi Create, and that user channel you are trying to install from has apparently switched to being private. Instead, follow [the official directions](https://github.com/apple/turicreate#installation) and install from PyPI (after activating your env).

```
conda activate my_env
pip install turicreate
```

**Do not install this in `base` env!** Be aware that once you use `pip install` in a Conda env, the env is effectively unstable, and can no longer be managed reliably by Conda. For this reason, always install PyPI packages last or use an environment YAML file. If you know that the package has dependencies ([they can usually be found in the `setup.py`](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/5.7.1/src/python/setup.py#L115)) that are available from Conda, install those first through Conda. I strongly encourage following the best practice recommendations found in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

Comment: Yes i got the answer ....I want to add one more point if user is working on linux then the command which works

"sudo pip install turicreate"

but after activation of new_environment    and turicreate doesn't support to python 3.7

Comment: While `sudo` is needed for very particular installations, typically nothing in a Conda env ever requires it.