# How do I install turicreate with anadonda on windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, turi-create

I am trying to install Turicreate on windows 10 with anaconda and python 3.7and pip version 19.3

```
Command: **conda create -n virtual_environment_name anaconda
           conda activate virtual_environment_name 
           pip install -U turicreate**
```

in anaconda virtual environment.
This gives the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MeghaNandini\Anaconda3\envs\vireve\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open

buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\MEGHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mwo8zqcl\\turicreate\\setup.py'
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install turicreate in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068783/unable-to-install-turicreate-in-anaconda)

Comment: Also, not that you must be running Windows Subsystem for Linux - [Turi Create does not support Windows](https://github.com/apple/turicreate#supported-platforms).

Comment: @merv, I am running the above command in Anaconda virtual environment

conda activate vireve
pip install -U turicreate

Answer (score 0):

Turi-create is not directly supported in Windows.  You must use the WSL linux environment, see [the WSL install guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

- Install WSL. I would suggest the latest Ubuntu distro as a lot of software has easy installation on ubuntu and it's widely used.
- Open a command line and use the `bash` command to start the linux bash shell.  Note that python 2 may still be the default, so if you want to use python 3, use the `python3` command where it says `python`.
- Install pip:

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install python3-pip`
- Create a virtual env as usual

  - `sudo pip install virtualenv`,
  - `virtualenv venv`.
  - `cd venv`
- Follow the [turi linux install instructions](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/LINUX_INSTALL.md).